# How to check if attribute exist in class in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class ProductAttributeValue {
    related_fields_last_updated_at?: Date;
}


console.log('related_fields_last_updated_at' in new 
 ProductAttributeValue());

console.log((new ProductAttributeValue()).hasOwnProperty('related_fields_last_updated_at'));
```

I have tried `in`, `hasOwnProperty()`. They are both not working.

Comment: The code that you added is just a class type... Can you provide the example testing with `in` and `hasOwnProperty` ?

Comment: Can you add what you've tried with `in and hasOwnProperty `

Comment: You don't initialise the property at all, so it's not there. `in` and `hasOwnProperty` confirming its absence is correct.

Comment: Oh the problem is is just a field in the class which compiled JS code that property is not used in the class at all and being removed.

Comment: It's not "removed". The property was never *there*. That's what an optional property *is* - it might not be present. If you want it to be *there* but potentially `undefined`, then *do not make it optional* make it `related_fields_last_updated_at: Date | null = null` or similar.

Comment: I mean the field stripped by TS once transpiled. Well it is not about optional or not but being used in the class or not. If I use it in the class then that property will be kept

Comment: Yes, it's TS annotation for classes. It doesn't exist at runtime. As with the entirety of the type system.